# How to use JSON data to output a formatted nested array?

Tags: python, json

First, any object that doesn't contain the latitude and longitude are going to be filtered out. I will input a url that contains the following inputed JSON. I want to then parse that JSON data and use that data to output the following as a JSON array in the format [latitude, longitude, location]. How do I do this?(Note: the latitude and longitude that are in strings need to converted to float numbers)

```
import json
import urllib.request

def getData(url):
    dictionary = {}
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    content = response.read().decode()
    response1 = json.loads(content)
    for i in response1:
        for element in i:
            if element == 'longitude' and element == 'latitude':
                float(i['longitude'])
                float(i['latitude'])
                dictionary.update(i)
    total = [[_.get("latitude"), _.get("longitude"), _.get("location")] for _ in dictionary]
    return json.dumps(total)
```

Input:

```
[{"capital": "Yes", "latitude": "35.6895", "longitude": "139.6917", "location": "Tokyo"}, 
{"capital": "Yes","latitude": "39.9042", "longitude": "116.4074", "location": "Beijing"}, 
{"capital": "No", "location": "Shanghai"}, {"capital": "No", "location": 
"Osaka"}]
```

Expected Output:

```
"[[35.6895, 139.6917, "Tokyo"], [39.9042, 116.4074, "Beijing"]]"
```

Comment: That loop doesn't do anything for several reasons. And you don't need it. With your current code you should be 99% of the way there, no? The only thing missing should be that the numbers remain strings, not floats, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
import json


response = [{"capital": "Yes", "latitude": "35.6895", "longitude": "139.6917", "location": "Tokyo"}, 
{"capital": "Yes","latitude": "39.9042", "longitude": "116.4074", "location": "Beijing"}, 
{"capital": "No", "location": "Shanghai"}, {"capital": "No", "location": 
"Osaka"}]

lst = [[float(i["latitude"]), float(i["longitude"]), i["location"] ] for i in response if ("latitude" in i) and ('longitude' in i)]
print(json.dumps(lst))
```

**Output:**

```
[[35.6895, 139.6917, "Tokyo"], [39.9042, 116.4074, "Beijing"]]
```

Comment: Don't you also need to parse the JSON data in the url?

Comment: i have used above as an example...in your case `response1` == `response`